# Plot the element-wise product of two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm very new to python, I wanted to write a program that multiplies elements present inside two arrays and plots a graph
How should I correct the code?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x=(np.double[0.1,0.001,0.0001,0.0001,0.00001])
y=(np.double[0.1,0.001,0.0001,0.0001,0.00001])
m=len(x)
n=len(y)

for m in range(0,m):
for n in range(0,n):
plt.plot[x(m),y(n)]

plt.show()
```

Comment: Well, to begin with, your `x` and `y` are declared incorrectly.

Comment: How is this code supposed to be indented?

Comment: I want 0.1 to be multiplied with 0.1 , 0.01 * 0.01 and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = np.array([0.1, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.00001] )
plt.plot(x ** 2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If `x` and `y` are different, use:

```
x = np.array([...]) # replace [...] with your list
y = np.array([...])
plt.plot(x * y)
plt.show()
```